# Dealing with 5,000 attributes

Tags: mysql, attributes, data-mining

I have a data set which contains 5,000 + attributes
The tables looks like below

```
id attr1 attr2, attr3
a  0         1       0
a  1         0       0
a  0         0       0
a  0         0       1
```

I wish to represent each record on a single row for example the table below to make it more amenable to data mining via clustering.

```
id, attr1, attr2, attr3
a     1       1        1
```

I have tried a multitude of ways of doing this
I have tried importing it into a MYSQL DB and getting the max value for each attribute (they can only be 1 or zero for each ID) but a table cant hold the 5,000 + attributes.

I have tried using the pivot function in excel and getting the Max Value per attribute but the number of columns a pivot can handle is far less than the 5,000 I'm currently looking at.

I have tried importing it into Tableua but that also suffers from the fact it cant handle so many records

I just want to get Table 2 in either a text/CSV file or a database table

Can anyone suggest anything at all, a piece of software or something i have not yet considered

Comment: What form is the data currently in? A text file with *really* long lines as your sample implies? You'll almost certainly need to write a custom script; Perl (the Purely Eclectic Rubbish Lister) is the abstruse champion of the field with Python being its more readable cousin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Python script which does what you ask for

```
def merge_rows_by_id(path):
    rows = dict()
    with open(path) as in_file:
        header = in_file.readline().rstrip()
        for line in in_file:
            fields = line.split()
            id, attributes = fields[0], fields[1:]
            if id not in rows:
                rows[id] = attributes
            else:
                rows[id] = [max(x) for x in zip(rows[id], attributes)]

    print (header)
    for id in rows:
        print ('{},{}'.format(id, ','.join(rows[id])))

 merge_rows_by_id('my-data.txt')
```

Which was written for clarity more than maximum efficiency, although it's pretty efficient. However, this will still leave you with lines with 5000 attributes, just fewer of them.

I've seen this data "structure" too often used in bioinformatics where the researchers just say "put everything we know about "a" on one row, and then the set of "everything" doubles, and re-doubles, etc. I've had to teach them about [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to make an RDBM handle what they've got. Usually, `attr_1…n` are from one trial and `attr_n+1…m` is from a second trial, and so on which allows for a sensible normalization of the data.

Comment: Hi MSW, Thanks for this, its exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Glad to hear it; upvotes are a StackOverflow way of showing appreciation (in addition to accepting the answer).

Comment: Let me emphasize that the answer is **write a converter yourself**. This site is for programming questions, and writing such a data transformation yourself is a *really* easy job with languages such as Python. IMHO, @msw should only have pointed you to the fact that this is probably easier to write yourself than to load the data into a SQL database, or learn another tool. +1 for doing things the *programmer* way.

Comment: Let *me* emphasize that I wrote it for my own curiosity and decided to post it and my coding preceded Mr. Smith's request for code. It is also trivial proof-of-concept code which contains no rocket science and is quite absent decent error checking (e.g. a row with too few fields will silently break it). Furthermore, it still doesn't solve his problem.